# Time format saved as short but retrieving as general date

Tags: .net, ms-access, datagridview

When i save time as short date in my visual studio program into an access database it saves so(as short date e.g 07:30 or 18:30). But when i retrieve it shows as a long date (12/30/1899 07:30 AM or 12/30/1899 18:30 PM). I select the dates from a combo box of which the times i have added myself but when i retrieve the data it is through a query which displays the data in a datagridview. i programmed it using visual basic in visual studio 2010 ultimate.

Still new to posting questions on the site but this first block saves to database and the second one retrieves:
To save:
         

*TblAttendanceTableAdapter.InsertAttendance(number, currentModule, fname, sname, CurrentUser, Date.Today, cmbFrom.SelectedItem.ToString, cmbTo.SelectedItem.ToString)*

To retrieve:
        

         *Dim userdate As String = dtpDate.Value.ToShortDateString*

```
    Dim records = From students In ESADataSet.tblAttendance
                  Where students.ModuleCode = currentModule And students.Date1 =         userdate
                  Order By students.StudentNumber
                  Select students


    dgvAttendance.DataSource = records.AsDataView
```

Comment: Why are you converting it to a string at all?

Comment: Please post how you add times to the ComboBox

Comment: i simply entered the times myself i.e from 07:30 up to 20:30 so the user selects these times they cant enter their own values

Comment: I'm actually not sure why i just thought that would be better for some reason...let me try changing that

Comment: just tried it now it gives the "Specified cast not valid" error when i take off the .ToString